# Fourier transform and characteristic function of an interval

Tags: fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

If we define the Fourier transform of a function $f$ as the function $$\mathcal{F}(f)(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-ixt}f(x)\,dx,$$ how can I prove that $$\mathcal{F}(h)(t)=\chi_{[-b,b]}(t),$$ where $\chi$ denotes the characteristic function of the interval $[-b,b]$ and $h$ is defined as $$h(x) = \sqrt{2\pi}\big(2\frac{\sin(bx)}{x}\big).$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb R}\chi_{[-b,\,b]}(t)e^{ixt}dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-b}^be^{ixt}dt=\frac{e^{ibx}-e^{-ibx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,ix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{2}{x}\sin bx=\frac{1}{2\pi}h(x),$$inverting the Fourier transform gives$$\chi_{[-b,\,b]}(t)=(2\pi)^{-3/2}\int_{\Bbb R}h(x)e^{-ixt}dx.$$I'd double-check your powers of $2\pi$ if I were you. Note that$$\mathcal{F}(h)(0)=2\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\sin bx dx}{x}=2\pi=2\pi\chi_{[-b,\,b]}(0)$$for $b>0$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to edit it, it is $\sqrt{2\pi}$ instead of $2\pi$.

Comment: @djpolin I've updated my answer to reflect your edit in the definition of $\mathcal{F}$, but I think you still have an error; I think you want the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in your definition of $h$ to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ instead.

Comment: I've checked the paper I'm following and the definition is with $\sqrt{2\pi}$, but I think you're right!

Comment: @djpoliri Could you link to the paper?

Comment: I don't have it in digital format... But the paper is: Sums of distances between points on a sphere - an application of the theory of irregularities of distribution to discrete geometry, by József Beck, published in Mathematika, 31 (1984), pages 33-41. The function $h$ is defined in page 37 in the multidimensional case, but you'll see that the problem is the same.

Comment: @djpoliri I can't get past the paywall, but I'll trust you. There's probably just a mistake in the paper. With Foruier transforms, it's easily done. That's why I computed $\mathcal{F}(h)(0)$ as a sanity check.